# Remove fields in the checkout page in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

Im trying to remove some fields form the checkout page (specifically: postcode, city, address 2)

First was a problem to remove the city field,  I went to: International / Locations them I selected country and when I tried to remove the field "city" I couldn't, PrestaShop said the following message:

```
"The city field (in tab Address) is required"
```

So after some google, I found out I need to modify:  classes/Address.php

I commented the whole line 134 that said:

```
'city' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isCityName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 64],
```

The problem persisted, and I still got the same message, so I edit the file classes/AddressFormat.php

I commented the line 63 that said "city":

```
   /** @var array Default required form fields list */
    public static $requireFormFieldsList = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'address1',
        // 'city',
        'Country:name',
    ];
```

Now, I finally was available to remove the field. But the issue still persit. Let me explain my self:

If you go to the checkout page, you can see the postal code and city field.

[Screenshot - Address field default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yswp5.jpg)

But, when I select the country, everything looks like is supposed to look.

[Screenshot - Address After selecting country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrBXu.jpg)

Any idea? How can I do, so i can remove the postcode and the city field?

Btw, my cache is off, but, I had cleaned my cache (in the performance page) and also I cleaned the cache on my browser. Also, I deleted this folder: /var/cache/prod/

[Cache disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcqVe.jpg)
[Field selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDawH.jpg)

Thanks guys

I use Prestashop: 1.7.7.2

Comment: You have revised the checkout fields for a specific country, so when checkout form opens first time, no country is selected and shows city and other field and when you select country it hides.
If you just want to hide the options, they are optional as per your screenshot. Then you can hide them via css or javascript.

Comment: That could work, but how can i totally remove thise options from the template? In the .tpl / php file

Answer (score 2):

For this to happen you just need to alter **one file**. The file we alter is a core file so make sure to make a backup before you start editing. We will make a filter which checks if the value for example `postcode` is in the filter. When the value is in the filter it will not create a form-field anymore.

1. Open file `Yourstore/classes/form/CustomerAddressFormatter.php`.
2. Search for `public function getFormat()` and navigate to the section `foreach ($fields as $field) {`

Below `foreach ($fields as $field) {` we add

```
    // In this case the fields postcode, adress1 and address2 will be removed from the Addresses form
    $ignorefields = ['postcode', 'address1', 'address2'];
    if (!in_array($field, $ignorefields)) {
```

Then we keep scrolling down until we find `$format[$formField->getName()] = $formField;`. Under this line we add a bracket `}` to close the function.

So all together you will now have a new function like this:

```
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
    // Add whatever value you which to hide to the array $ignorefields to remove it from the Addresses form-field.
    // Available values: address1, address2, postcode, city, State, phone, phone_mobile, company, vat_number
    $ignorefields = ['postcode', 'address1', 'address2'];
    if (!in_array($field, $ignorefields)) {
        $formField = new FormField();
        $formField->setName($field);
        $fieldParts = explode(':', $field, 2);
        if (count($fieldParts) === 1) {
            if ($field === 'postcode') {
                if ($this->country->need_zip_code) {
                    $formField->setRequired(true);
                }
            } elseif ($field === 'phone') {
                $formField->setType('tel');
            } elseif ($field === 'dni' && null !== $this->country) {
                if ($this->country->need_identification_number) {
                    $formField->setRequired(true);
                }
            }
        } elseif (count($fieldParts) === 2) {
            list($entity, $entityField) = $fieldParts;
            $formField->setType('select');
            $formField->setName('id_' . strtolower($entity));
            if ($entity === 'Country') {
                $formField->setType('countrySelect');
                $formField->setValue($this->country->id);
                foreach ($this->availableCountries as $country) {
                    $formField->addAvailableValue(
                        $country['id_country'],
                        $country[$entityField]
                    );
                }
            } elseif ($entity === 'State') {
                if ($this->country->contains_states) {
                    $states = State::getStatesByIdCountry($this->country->id, true);
                    foreach ($states as $state) {
                        $formField->addAvailableValue(
                            $state['id_state'],
                            $state[$entityField]
                        );
                    }
                    $formField->setRequired(true);
                }
            }
        }
        $formField->setLabel($this->getFieldLabel($field));
        if (!$formField->isRequired()) {
            $formField->setRequired(
                array_key_exists($field, $required)
            );
        }
        $format[$formField->getName()] = $formField;
    } // Add bracket to close our new function - Crezzur
}
```